# MPI fortran programm hangs with a limit numbers of mpi processes

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel

I am working on a MPI application which hangs when it is launched with more than 2071 MPI processes. I have succeeded to make a small reproducer of this:

```
program main
use mpi
integer :: ierr,rank
call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierr)
if (rank.eq.0) print *,'Start'
call test_func(ierr)
if (ierr.ne.0) call exit(ierr)
call mpi_finalize(ierr)
if (rank.eq.0) print *,'Stop'

contains

subroutine test_func(ierr)
integer, intent(out) :: ierr
real :: send,recv
integer :: i,j,status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE),mpi_rank,mpi_size,ires
character(len=10) :: procname
real(kind=8) :: t1,t2
ierr=0
call mpi_comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,mpi_size,ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,mpi_rank,ierr)
call mpi_get_processor_name(procname, ires, ierr)
call mpi_barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
t1 = mpi_wtime()
do j=0,mpi_size-1
  if (mpi_rank.eq.j) then
    do i=0,mpi_size-1
      if (i.eq.j) cycle
      call MPI_RECV(recv,1,MPI_REAL,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr)
      if (ierr.ne.0) return
      if (i.eq.mpi_size-1) print *,'Rank ',j,procname,' done'
    enddo
  else
    call MPI_SEND(send,1,MPI_REAL,j,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
    if (ierr.ne.0) return
  endif
enddo
call mpi_barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
t2 = mpi_wtime()
if (mpi_rank.eq.0) print*,"time send/recv = ",t2-t1
end subroutine test_func
end program main
```

When I run this program with less than 2071 MPI processes then it works but when I run it with more than 2072 processes then it hangs as if there are deadlocks on the send/recv.
The outputs running the programm with I_MPI_DEBUG=5 are

```
[0] MPI startup(): Intel(R) MPI Library, Version 2019 Update 9 Build 20200923 (id: abd58e492)
[0] MPI startup(): Copyright (C) 2003-2020 Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
[0] MPI startup(): library kind: release
[0] MPI startup(): libfabric version: 1.10.1-impi
[0] MPI startup(): libfabric provider: verbs;ofi_rxm
[0] MPI startup(): Rank Pid Node name Pin cpu
[0] MPI startup(): 0 48487 r30i0n0 {0,24}
...
[0] MPI startup(): 2070 34737 r30i4n14 {18,19,20,42,43,44}
[0] MPI startup(): I_MPI_CC=icc
[0] MPI startup(): I_MPI_CXX=icpc
[0] MPI startup(): I_MPI_FC=ifort
[0] MPI startup(): I_MPI_F90=ifort
[0] MPI startup(): I_MPI_F77=ifort
[0] MPI startup(): I_MPI_ROOT=/data_local/sw/intel/RHEL7/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mpi
[0] MPI startup(): I_MPI_MPIRUN=mpirun
[0] MPI startup(): I_MPI_HYDRA_RMK=lsf
[0] MPI startup(): I_MPI_HYDRA_TOPOLIB=hwloc
[0] MPI startup(): I_MPI_INTERNAL_MEM_POLICY=default
[0] MPI startup(): I_MPI_EXTRA_FILESYSTEM=1
[0] MPI startup(): I_MPI_EXTRA_FILESYSTEM_FORCE=lustre
[0] MPI startup(): I_MPI_DEBUG=5
```

**Question 1 : Is there a reason explaining this behavior?**

Notice that if I change the send/recv communication pattern by either a bcast one

```
do j=0,mpi_size-1
  if (mpi_rank.eq.j) then
    call MPI_BCAST(send,1,MPI_REAL,j,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  else
    call MPI_BCAST(recv,1,MPI_REAL,j,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  endif
  if (ierr.ne.0) return  
  print *,'Rank ',j,procname,' done'
enddo
```

or an allgather one

```
call MPI_ALLGATHER(MPI_IN_PLACE,0,MPI_DATATYPE_NULL,recv,1,MPI_REAL,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
print *,'Rank ',mpi_rank,procname,' done '
```

then the programm runs (faster of course) but with up to 4000 MPI processes (I did not try with more MPI processes). However, I can not change the communication send/recv pattern in the original application with the bcast or the allgather ones.

**Question 2 :** When I run the original application with 2064 MPI processes (86 nodes having 24 cores), the consummed memory for MPI buffers is around 60 GB per node and with 1032 MPI processes (43 nodes having 24 cores) it is around 30 GB per node. **Is there a way (environment variables...) to reduce this amount of consummed memory?**

Many thanks in advance for your help

Thierry

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. If you have two different questions, it is.often better or even necessary to post it in two different question posts so that it is possible to actually answer your post in a single answer post. Questions that are too broad can be closed. See also [ask].

Comment: Regarding the deadlock, it could just be running out of resources due the large number of outstanding Send operations (which MPI will probably be trying to buffer so they can be sent asynchronously). What happens if you replace MPI_Send with MPI_Ssend? This won't be as efficient but since MPI_Ssend is guaranteed to be synchronous (it won't return until it has matched with a receive call) you won't be consuming so many system resources. If it runs with Ssend but not Send then that would point to an MPI resource limitation.

Comment: This looks mightily like an mpi_alltoall - is there a reason you can't use that in the full code? As for the memory question that just looks like your code using a lot of replicated objects - but can't say for certain without more details. Also note use of real( 8 ) is not good practice, it is not  guaranteed to be double precision, and not guaranteed to be supported by your compiler

Comment: an other trick worth trying is to add `MPI_Barrier()` in the `do j` loop every `n` iterations (`n` has to be determined empirically. `1` is very likely an overkill fwiw). And/or post all `MPI_Irecv()` and then `MPI_Waitall()`. The goal is to reduce the number of unexpected messages that comes with some side effects such as high resource consumption, slowdown and deadlocks.

Comment: @DavidHenty: mpi_Ssend hangs after 562 exchanges with 2071 mpi proceses run. And as you have mentioned it was very slow beforre hanging

Comment: @IanBush: the original application is using a distributed 4D transpose (sucessive 3D transposes) inside a loop (24 4D transpose are possibles) and sent/received size are computed on fly. Thus, mpi_alltoall or mpi_alltoallv is hardly usable for this application.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: I have tried with MPI_Irecv (using a MPI_Waitall for the mpi_size -1 received requests): it works for 2071 MPI processes but it hangs for 2072 MPI processes (only 2060 processes complete the full exchange)

Comment: did you `MPI_Barrier()` between posting the `MPI_Irecv()` and issuing the `MPI_Send()`?

Comment: @braconnier I'll just comment that for the 3D case, typically in FFTs, mpi_alltoall and mpi_alltoallv are the standard way to do it - see for instance any number of plane wave DFT codes. I would be very surprised if what is used there does not extend to 4D.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: with or without MPI_Barrier(), np=2071 works and np=2072 hangs

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous remarks that it looks like you start too many recvs on a single process, and the MPI implementation may run out of some internal buffer.

I would not recommend using Ssends or introducing barriers, though. Just replace all the MPI_Recv's by MPI_Irecv's, and the MPI_Send's by MPI_Isend's.
This does not introduce any synchronization and avoids deadlocks. You can then also change the order in which you post the sends and recv's arbitrarily, for instance, you could pair sends and recvs instead of doing the recvs in a big for-loop for each outer loop iteration.

Concerning your second question about the memory consumption: probably the same: the number of recvs you post in your inner loop grows linearly with the number of processes, and so thus the amount of memory needed to handle these outstanding messages.

Finally, I also agree with previous comments that this looks very much like a case for a collective MPI call, which one exactly depends on the application code that you don't show here, but an MPI_Alltoallv may be a good one to look at.